# Headless mode in cucumber capybara ruby automation

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I have seeing a lot of similar question, but non of them have help me to understand.
how to run my .feature file in headless mode using chromedrive, selenium, capybara, ruby and cucumber.
this is my env.rb:
require_relative 'helper.rb'

```
BROWSER = ENV['BROWSER']

World(Helper)

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|

  if BROWSER.eql?('chrome_headless')

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
        :browser => :chrome,
        :desired_capabilities => Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
          'chromeOptions' => {
            'args' => [ "headless", "window-size=1440x768", "disable-gpu"]
          }
        )
      )
    elsif BROWSER.eql?('chrome')
        Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,browser: :chrome)
        
    end
  end

Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.default_driver =:selenium
   Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1440,768)
end

Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 60
```

this is my helper.rb:

```
 module Helper
 def take picture(file_name, res)
     file_path = "reports/screenshot/"
     dateTime = DateTime.now.to_s
     dateTime.split(':')
     date = dataHora[0..12].to_s+dataHora[14..15].to_s+dataHora[17..21].to_s
     picture = "#{file_path}#{date}#{nome_arquivo}-#{res}.png"
     temp_shot = page.save_screenshot(picture)
     shot = Base64.encode64(File.open(temp_shot, "rb").read)
     attach(shot, 'image/png')
 end
end
```

this is my step_definition file .rb
just a normal rb file containing capybara elements

```
 adm = LoginAdmin.new
 admInic = TelaInicialAdmin.new


   varGlobal = YAML.load(File.read('./configuracoesGlobaisTeste.yaml'))
    @nomeOferta = varGlobal["nomeOferta"]
     @nomeProduto = varGlobal["nomeProduto"]

       Dado('que acessei a página da Vivo') do
            acesso.load
             end

   Quando('clicar em Entrar posso digitar minhas credenciais ') do 
        page.driver.browser.navigate.refresh
        sleep 3
        inicio.btnEntrar.click
        inicio.usuario.set @usuario
        inicio.senha.set @senha
        inicio.btnAcessarConta.click
     end
```

is there missing something?
this is how i run the automation on terminal using the tag in my feature file:

```
cucumber -t@criarClienteCompraLojaClone
```

this command opens a browser using a GUI. i wish not open GUI. I wish to perform a headless test.
i have just try every tutorial in stackoverflow and google.
Please any suggestion will help!

Comment: Where are you actually setting the BROWSER environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

My headless works updating the env.rb file for this:

```
require_relative 'helper.rb'

BROWSER = ENV['BROWSER']


#HEADLESS
World(Helper)

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome  do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome,
    options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: %w[headless no-sandbox disable-gpu]))
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
config.default_driver =:headless_chrome
#Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1440,768)
end

Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 60
```

Answer (score 0):

My `env.rb` file only contains the following lines of Capybara config adjustment:

```rb
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```